# Parse a text file line by line and use $line in nextflow bash

Tags: nextflow

I have a bash script that works fine on terminal. It takes a text file from user, reads it line by line, and does operation by using entry in each line as search query.

```
#!/bin/bash
mkdir "final_loc_tf"

while read BED;
do
cat results/intersect/*/$BED | sortBed | bedtools merge -c 4 -o collapse > "final_loc_tf/"$BED"_final.bed"

done < $1
```

I want to implement this into my nextflow but no success. I have seen couple of examples parsing csv files but couldn't make it work on my text file.

Here is my nextflow file trying to implement the bash file. But I am not able to parse the text file, as it doesn't give me any output files.

```
#!/usr/bin/env nextflow
nextflow.enable.dsl=2

params.bed = file("results/all_bed.txt")

process MERGE {

    publishDir 'results/final', mode: 'copy', overwrite: false

    input:
    file file_list

    output:
    path '*'

    script:
    """
    bash test.sh $file_list
    """
}

workflow {
    bed_ch=params.bed

    MERGE(bed_ch)
}
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nextflow processes are executed independently and are isolated from each other inside the working directory (i.e. `./work`). If you have a look at your `.command.err` inside your process working directory, you'll likely see errors like:

```
cat: results/intersect/*/<bed>: No such file or directory
```

This is because the `results` directory (containing the BED files beneath it, i.e. `results/intersect/*/$BED`) has not been staged into the process working directory. The reason you didn't see an error in your Nextflow output is that, by default, the return value of a pipeline is the exit status of the last command. In your pipeline, the last command (i.e. `bedtools merge`) probably completes successfully and returns exit status zero. The option you want to add is called 'pipefail', `man bash`:

> pipefail
>
> If set, the return value of a pipeline is the value of the last
> (rightmost) command to exit with a non-zero status, or zero if all
> commands in the pipeline exit successfully. This option is disabled by
> default.

So to ensure that your pipeline does not mask errors, you can add the following to your `nextflow.config` to have it applied to all processes:

```
process {

  shell = [ '/bin/bash', '-euo', 'pipefail' ]
}
```

And to ensure that your workflow is portable, you will need some way to stage each of the required input files into the process working directory. A better way to do what you want would be to just pass in the files that you want merged explicitly. One way would be to use the [`fromFilePairs`](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/channel.html#fromfilepairs) factory method, which gives you a group key. We can handle [multiple input files](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/process.html#multiple-input-files) by using a wildcard (i.e. `*`) to control the name of staged files, for example:

```
params.bed_files = './path/to/*/*.bed'
params.outdir = './results'


process MERGE {

    tag { sample }

    publishDir "${params.outdir}/MERGE", mode: 'copy'

    input:
    tuple val(sample), path('bed_files/*.bed')

    output:
    tuple val(sample), path("${sample}_final.bed")

    """
    cat bed_files/*.bed |
        sortBed |
        bedtools merge -c 4 -o collapse \\
        > "${sample}_final.bed"
    """
}

workflow {

    bed_ch = Channel.fromFilePairs( params.bed_files, size: -1 )

    MERGE(bed_ch)
}
```

Comment: Hi Steve,
That works great for me, and thanks for the neat explanation. Could you possibly please explain how the script fromFilePairs works for each unique file pair, say for SOX21.bed file?  I was unnecessarily writing script to get unique file names and then use them as search query in my bed_files path.

Comment: Also, I can see that echo ${sample} outputs SOX21_intersected (I was guessing it would be SOX21_intersected.bed).

Comment: @PooranDewari Briefly, the `fromFilePairs` factory method uses the [`readPrefix`](https://github.com/nextflow-io/nextflow/blob/v23.04.0/modules/nextflow/src/main/groovy/nextflow/Channel.groovy#L562-L624) helper function to return a part of a filename matching a specified glob pattern starting from the beginning of the name up to the last matching group. If you wanted the name of the file instead, you _could_ (but probably don't need to) use a custom grouping strategy by supplying a closure, for example: `bed_ch = Channel.fromFilePairs( params.bed_files, size: -1 ) { it.name }`.